# Axis Ordering of Integers in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot in ggplot2 showing confidence intervals of samples

```
sample.means%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = id,y=means))+geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-1.96*sds/sqrt(30),
                    ymax=means+1.96*sds/sqrt(30)))+
  coord_flip()
```

However the axis is not in numerical order.  The "id" column is an integer and I do not know why they are not in order.[image]

Comment: it is most likely that `id` is actually stored in your data.frame as a `character` or `factor`. what does `str(sample.means)` return?

Comment: ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(id)),y=means)) + geom_point()

Comment: (or `...=as.integer(as.character(id)),...` if the distinction between integers and reals matters in this case)

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the correct direction, although before I was using `sample.means$id=row.names(sample.means)` which was making it a character.  Even though I later used `as.integer(id)` it was not changing it from a char.  I adjusted the code to `sample.means$id=as.integer(row.names(sample.means))`.